# How to write a raw sql in rails scope?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is scope I have.

```
scope :abc, -> (start_date, end_date) {
  find_by_sql("select * from xys where created_at >= '#{start_date}' and created_at <= '#{end_date}'")
}
```

When I am executing the above scope with the following command it returns blank array.

```
XYZ.abc(start_date, end_date)
```

Above command generates the proper sql which I can see in the log. And when I execute that sql into mysql it returns data.

I know How to write scope with help of select, where etc...

Question here is, I want to write pure sql inside the scope. How can I write that?

Comment: why do you want raw sql in scope?

Comment: What is a better way to handle raw sql?

Comment: if you are really going to select from your model's table, why do you need raw sql? if it is going to be join of multiple tables, use views.

Comment: In my case I have one Roda application which dumps a SQL statement which grabs certain transactions, another (Admin, Rails app) is supposed to show only these transactions, the view is done with active admin which in turn wants to see a scope.

Answer (score 5):

The right way would be to use the following:

```
scope :abc, ->(start_date, end_date) {
  where("created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?", start_date, end_date)
}
```

By calling `find_by_sql` you're mixing ActiveRecord's scoping system with the `find_by_sql` method (which I'd only recommend for complicated SQL, which yours is not).

Scoping is actually one of the strengths of the framework (you can, for example, easily combine them together `Object.abc(date, date).some_other_scope` to create readable queries).

Since you're not scoping, no models are instantiated for you, and the database isn't queried immediately (which allows you to chain scopes); a scope method typically returns something of a ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_[Classname] and not an array.

**Update**: With today's knowledge I'd write this query as follows (using [Range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Range.html)):

```
scope :abc, ->(start_date, end_date) { where(created_at: (start_date..end_date)) }
```

With Rails 3 you can even write endless ranges (created_at >= start_date), e.g.

```
scope :abc, ->(start_date) { where(created_at: (start_date...)) }
```